# how to use datasourceRealm Java

Tags: java, tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I'm using `DataSourceRealm` with the code below:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSourceRealm dss = new DataSourceRealm(); 
DataSourceRealm ds =  (DataSourceRealm) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/InfoFeedProxyDataBase");
// i'm getting connot cast DataSource to DataSourceRealm
```

Here's my configuration in tomcat:

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              name="InfoFeedProxyDataBase"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ppe3-1"
              username="root"
              password="" />
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="InfoFeedProxyDataBase"
       localDataSource="true"
       digest="MD5"
       roleNameCol="role"
       userCredCol="password"
       userNameCol="login"
       userRoleTable="roles"
       userTable="users" />
```

I've tried this code:

```
 DataSourceRealm dsr = new DataSourceRealm(); 
 dsr.start();
```

May I know how can I use `DataSourceRealm` Object in Java?